# Executing javascript in Silverlight with Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, xaml

I am trying to execute a piece of javascript in my silverlight application.
Pretty simple example that I have created... Just a single button that tries to execute 
this line of code...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   HtmlPage.Window.Eval("alert('hi');");
}
```

The alert window does come up but it freezes firefox, I have to force quit firefox it never comes back to life.... has anyone ran into this??

I thought maybe a firefox plugin was causing the problem but I have disabled them all with the same results.

The only way I can get it work is if I go to `about:config` in firefox and set `dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.npctrl.dll` to `false`

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think I partially figured this out...

I added this parameter to my Silverlight hosting page...

```
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

So the whole `<div>`

```
 <div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="source" value="ClientBin/JavascriptSLTrigger.xap" />
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
        <param name="windowless" value="true" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration: none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
</div>
```